# Extension of Hall's Condition for general graphs.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Motivation: What restrictions would allow us to replace the condition in Tutte's theorem for perfect matching by just Hall's condition.

Extension of Hall's condition for general graphs: If for all independent sets $S \subseteq V$ in a graph satisfy $N(S) \geq |S|$, where $N(S)$ denotes the cardinality of the neighbor set of $S$ and $V$ is the vertex set.

Does there exist an infinite family of graphs such that:

1. $|V| = n$ is even and the graph is connected.
2. They satisfy the above condition.
3. Tutte's theorem is violated i.e. there is no perfect matching.
4. Every vertex has degree $\geq \Omega(n)$.

Note that if you relax the condition 4 to just being a dense graph you can get such graphs with joining $K_{2r}$ to any graph satisfying the first 3 conditions by an edge. Similarly, if the graph is allowed to be disconnected you can have a disjoint union of two odd cliques.

If there are such graphs what extra conditions would ensure that there are no such graphs?

Comment: What if you add a new vertex $p$ to the graph $3K_{2n+1}$ and edges joining $p$ to all the other vertices?

Comment: It works :) if you post as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example.** For each positive integer $n,$ let $G_n$ be the graph of order $6n+4$ obtained by adding a new vertex $p$ to the graph $3K_{2n+1}$ and edges joining $p$ to all the other vertices.